# Keeping a tested version of my solution but allowing to continue working on other requests

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012, branching-and-merging

I have an ASP.NET MVC solution (VS2012) under TFS. Let's say I have the latest version on my hard drive (lets name it version X). I know this version is OK (tested and ready for moving to production but waiting for approval). Now I would like to work on another request on this solution.

**My question**: how can I preserve actual state of my solution BUT continue to work on this solution. At some point, when I get approbation, I will need to retrieve the version X from TFS and move it to production, then continue to develop my pending request.

How can I proceed? Using labels or branches?

Comment: For the record, which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: I use the online version http://tfs.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this using branches.

The day after our code cut off we cut a new branch from the Trunk. We then work with test to make sure this is stable, all bugs are fixed and merged back to Trunk.

This branch is then owned by the test team and anything that goes into it must be approved by them.

We also have seperate Daily and Buddy builds for this live branch. Test can use this to build the latest from that branch at any time.

Before deployment day the test team then build this live branch to create a package. This package is stable and tested. After this has been done, only exceptional circumstances will allow anything else to go into this designated deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Branching is the answer to this problem.

The best branching guidance I've seen is the "[Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/)".

It includes everything you need to make a decision on your branching structure, including pictures!

I recommend that you start with either the Basic or Standard branch plans, then see how badly you need something more complex.